# Part of this script that should get the ports of all running services doesnt give an output?

Tags: powershell

This script that iam working on used to work perfectly fine, but now the part that should give the ports of the running services isnt giving me an output for some reason and as iam pretty new to powershell i cant figure out why?

```
#Laufende Dienste
$Service = Get-Service | where{$_.Status -eq "Running"} 
Write-Host "Laufende Services:" -ForegroundColor Red 
foreach($x in $Service){
    Write-Host $x.ServiceName
    

}    


# Standard Dienste importen
$csvfile = Import-CSV -Path "K:\Example\Example.csv"
Foreach ($x in $csvfile) {
    Write-Host $x.Name
}

#Vergleichen der Liste und laufenden Dienst
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject (get-service|where{$_.Status -eq "Running"}).servicename -DifferenceObject (import-csv K:\Example\Example.csv ).name  -IncludeEqual 

Write-Host "Nur in Laufenden Diensten(<=) | In Laufenden Diensten und der Liste(=) | Nur in der Liste(=>)(WICHTIG)  " -ForegroundColor Green 

#Ports finden
Get-CimInstance Win32_Service -Filter "State='Running'" | ForEach {
    $service = $_
    # TCP first
    Get-NetTCPConnection -OwningProcess $_.ProcessId -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | 
       Select @{l="ServiceName";e={$service.Name}}, LocalPort}
```

Comment: The `#Ports finden` part for me works.. You could try to remove `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` to see if some error occurs. As aside, you can shorten the code for the Compare-Object line into `Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $Service.servicename -DifferenceObject $csvfile.name -IncludeEqual`. Since you already have those variables filled, no need to redo the Get-Service and Import-Csv call

Comment: Huh for me if i only try to  run the ports part it works but if i run the whole script it doesnt(doesnt give an output)

Comment: Perhaps then close PowerShell and start fresh. Maybe you did something earlier that causes problems. The only part I cannot check is where you import the csv because I don't have that file